# Passing JSON objects to jq arguments

Tags: json, bash, parameter-passing, jq, data-processing

Data sample - **sample.json** (full sample: https://pastebin.com/KFkVmc2M)

```
    {
      "ip": 3301234701,
      "_shodan": {
        "options": {
          "referrer": "7ae15507-f5cc-4353-b72e-5cc0b1c34c5e"
        },
      },
      "hash": -1056085507,
      "os": null,
      "title": "WHM Login",
      "opts": {
        "vulns": ["!CVE-2014-0160"],
        "heartbleed": "2017/08/29 09:57:30 196.196.216.13:2087 - SAFE\
        }
      },
      "isp": "Fiber Grid Inc",
      "http": {
        "redirects": [],
        "title": "WHM Login",
        "robots": null,
        "favicon": null,
        "host": "196.196.216.13",
        "html":
}
```

Script using jq which I hoped would work and haven't found a another solution yet.

```
   cat sample.json | jq \
   --arg key0   'Host' \
   --arg value0 '.host' \
   --arg key1   'Vulnerability' \
   --arg value1 '.opts.vulns[0]' \
   --arg key2   'ISP' \
   --arg value2 '.isp' \
   '. | .[$key0]= $value0 | .[$key1]=$value1 | .[$key2]=$value2' \
   <<<'{}'
```

The end result I hoped, but not getting:

```
{
  "Host": "196.196.216.13",
  "Vulnerability": "!CVE-2014-0160",
  "ISP": "Fiber Grid Inc"
}
```

Right now it just returns the object as a string and I've tried a lot of different ways to approach the problem. I am quite new to working with JSON and jq but based on what I've read so far, the solution might not be as simple as I'm wishing?

Simply put, why isn't the object being returned as a value of the sample.json object and what do I have to do, to make it work?

Thanks!

to: chepner

```
{
  "196.196.216.13":[
  "AS63119",
  "Fiber Grid Inc",
  "2017-08-29T06:57:22.546423",
  "!CVE-2014-0160"
],
"196.196.216.14":[
  "AS63119",
  "Fiber Grid Inc",
  "2017-08-29T06:57:22.546423",
  "!CVE-2014-0160"
]
}
```

Comment: Why do you need the variables? Just use `jq '{Host: .http.host, Vulnerability: .ops.vulns, IPS: .isp}' tmp.json`.

Comment: @chepner sure but it seemed to me that being able to simply call for different arguments would allow for a simpler way to structure my data. In the end with full dataset I would like my data structure to look smth like this: (added to the post)

Comment: Frankly, what it's doing is what I, as a user, would expect and hope for it to do. Evaluating data as code is bad practice in general (for security and predictability reasons among others), and *should* require explicit steps to be taken.

Comment: That said, it's certainly feasible to take code that accepts a JSON list and traverses down elements named (or numbered) by the elements in that list. I certainly *wouldn't* expect a full evaluator.

Comment: ...so, if I were to write an answer to this, its input / calling convention would look more like: `config='{"Host": ["host"],
     "Vulnerability": ["opts", "vulns", 0],
     "ISP": ["isp"]}'; jq --argjson config "$config" '...' <in.json`

Comment: @CharlesDuffy thanks for that code, pretty cool solution for getting the data. I'll definitely play around with that, but do you have any suggestions getting the output to the structure I have in the example?

Comment: The above lends itself to a function that, given a list of keys, performs a recursive lookup for each and returns the result; given that, one just needs another function to iterate over key/value pairs in the configuration, do the lookup against the input for each, and generate the output. That said, if I were inclined to write that function *right now*, I would have posted an answer, not a comment. (There are plenty of talented people in the `jq` tag -- I'd be very surprised if someone else didn't come up with an answer, whether that one or otherwise, somewhere in the next ~12 hours or so).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here's a variant solution using the approach suggested by @CharlesDuffy:

```
$ config='{"Host": ["http", "host"], 
           "Vulnerability": ["opts", "vulns", 0], 
           "ISP": ["isp"]}'
$ jq --argjson config "$config" '
   . as $in
   | $config
   | map_values( . as $p | $in | getpath($p) )' pastebin.json
```

Output:

```
{
  "Host": "196.196.216.13",
  "Vulnerability": "!CVE-2014-0160",
  "ISP": "Fiber Grid Inc"
}
```

This incidentally highlights @chepner's point: the care and maintenance required for $config is no less than the care and maintenance required for the corresponding jq query, whereas the jq query language -- by design -- offers far more flexibility.

Answer (score 2):

1. jq does not support the evaluation of jq expressions in the
   way that would be required for your attempt to work.  You could do some
   kind of shell interpolation, but it would be better to use JSON paths,
   e.g. rather than `--arg value0 .host`, you could write `--arg value0 "host"`, etc.  In the following, I've used `getpath/1`.
2. There is no need to prepend the jq filter with '. |'

Anyway, assuming the JSON contents of the pastebin are in pastebin.json, you could write:

```
  jq \
   --arg key0        Host \
   --argjson value0  '["http","host"]' \
   --arg key1        Vulnerability \
   --argjson value1  '["opts", "vulns", 0]' \
   --arg key2        ISP \
   --argjson value2  '["isp"]' \
   '. as $in
    | {}
    | .[$key0] = ($in|getpath($value0))
    | .[$key1] = ($in|getpath($value1))
    | .[$key2] = ($in|getpath($value2))' \
   pastebin.json
```

This would have the result:

```
{
  "Host": "196.196.216.13",
  "Vulnerability": "!CVE-2014-0160",
  "ISP": "Fiber Grid Inc"
}
```

Comment: Heh. I was expecting to do the work of writing `getpath` myself. :)

Comment: thanks, so I wasn't 100% off. Was trying to use `argjason` etc but didn't realize that, that's how you declare the `path` nor the `in/getpath` methods..
Do you have any tips for getting the data to the structure that it is in the last example? It has different data but the idea is the same.

Answer (score 1):

In response to the supplementary question ("to: chepner"):

The pastebin data does not contain "196.196.216.14" so the supplementary question is unclear, but you will probably want to start with:

```
jq '{(.ip_str): [.asn, .isp, .timestamp, opts.vulns[0] ]}' pastebin.json
```

This produces:

```
{
  "196.196.216.13": [
    "AS63119",
    "Fiber Grid Inc",
    "2017-08-29T06:57:22.546423",
    "!CVE-2014-0160"
  ]
}
```

The key point here is the pair of parentheses around `.ip_str`.

As mentioned elsewhere, the jq query is again so simple and straightforward that it seems doubtful that a parameterized version will offer any advantage.

Comment: thanks for this, the only problem with this, is that it produces `{}` around every response and not the result as a whole, like it is in the example. Neither is the `,` added after the end of an array which, with the correct use of `{}` would create an valid JSON

Comment: @user3086917 - Creating an array of objects in jq is trivial, but since you don't seem to have given a specific example or specific requirements, it's difficult to provide you with specific details of what you need.  In any case, based on what has been discussed, I'd advise you to stick with jq queries rather than trying to parameterize them in complete generality.